# Cards are all uneven

Tags: html, css, height, bootstrap-5, card

[image]

---------//////Question starts here/////---------------

I am trying to make all of my Bootstrap 5 *cards* even in standard view **and** responsive to mobile devices, but adjusting the height in CSS does not seem to work. Right now it is responsive, but the pictures are all stretched out. As far as the card's height they are all different sizes. I tried grabbing the card-text "class" and using truncate but it doesn't seem to help either. I feel like I'm so close. Im almost positive it has to do with the card-text class. Any thoughts? I've attached a picture to this question, and here is my code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Portfolio Projects</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min (15).css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- ===================== NavBar Starts from here====================== -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CHAZZY!</a>
        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
          aria-controls="navbarNav"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a
                class="nav-link active"
                aria-current="page"
                href="../index.html"
                >Home</a
              >
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="../About/index.html"
                >About</a
              >
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="../Projects/index.html"
                >Projects</a
              >
            </li>
      
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="https://chaz-carothers.netlify.app"
                >Tree.Link</a
              >
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a
                class="nav-link"
                href="../Contact/index.html"
                tabindex="-1"
                aria-disabled="true"
                >Contact</a
              >
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- ================== NavBar Ends ========================== -->

    <!-- ========================== Project Cards ======================== -->
    

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm mt-5 mb-5">
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
            <img src="../Projects/img/weather.jpeg" alt="Weather" />
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Weather API</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                This is a weather app I created using the ___ API. I added
                several other weather resources to provide extra information.
              </p>
              <a
                href="../WEATHER API/index.html"
                class="
                  btn btn-primary
                  row
                  d-flex
                  justify-content-center
                  align-content-center
                "
                >CLICK HERE</a
              >
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm mt-5 mb-5">
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
            <img
              src="../Projects/img/Skeletorrr.png"
              class="card- img-top"
              alt="skeletor"
            />

            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title.text-truncate">Whack-A-Skeletor</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                This is my version of a Whack-A-Mole game that I created using plain vanilla JavaScript. 
                Skeletor is the mole, and the game has background music to the Price Is Right. Once the user 
                is finished playing, Vincent Price's notorious laugh chimes in at the end.
              
              </p>
              <a
                href="https://pedantic-swartz-521f4d.netlify.app"
                class="
                  btn btn-primary
                  row
                  d-flex
                  justify-content-center
                  align-content-center
                "
                >CLICK HERE</a
              >
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm mt-5 mb-5">
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
            <img
              src="./img/badguys.png"
              class="card- img-top"
              alt="villain"
            />
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Disney Villain Page</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
                eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore.
              </p>
              <a
                href="https://dizney.netlify.app"
                class="
                  btn btn-primary
                  row
                  d-flex
                  justify-content-center
                  align-content-center
                "
                >CLICK HERE</a
              >
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>



        <div class="col-sm mt-5 mb-5">
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
            <img
              src="../Projects/img/memory.jpeg"
              class="card- img-top"
              alt="memory"
            />
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title.text-truncate">Harry Potter Memory Game</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                My 7 year old son's favorite movie is Harry Potter, so I programmed a memory game for him using JavaScript. 
              </p>
              <a
                href="../Projects/Memory Game/index.html"
                class="
                  btn btn-primary
                  row
                  d-flex
                  justify-content-center
                  align-content-center
                "
                >CLICK HERE</a
              >
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
      integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

-----------------/////And here is my CSS//// -------------

```
body {
  background-color: gray;
}
.card {
  transition: border-color 1s, box-shadow 0.5s;
}
.card:hover {
  border-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.card-title {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.film {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  .film {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
  .card {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .card-title {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  .img-card {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Bootstrap cards take up the height to fit the content within. Hence, since your images are all different heights, and the texts are also different in length, the cards are uneven. Adding a max-height to the card might help, though that will add a vertical scroll. You also have 2 Bootstrap css imports? The CDN is fine, you don't need the other one unless it's custom and the name is just Bootstrap.

Comment: Also @ChazCarothers can I just check. Your images all seem to be different dimensions and the length of each paragraph completely different too. What is the goal? Is it just to make sure the boxes all stretch to the same height? Because in my brain those are always going to be different heights unless the images and text are more uniform to each other.